# "Opulence is the end": has this a double meaning?

Tags: expressions, ambiguity

This quote in its context means "death caused by the opulence (wealthy life)". Opulence is the end because it can make people do things they wouldn't do otherwise.

My question is: can this quote also reference to an achievement I want to goal? Like "the opulence is my objective! (the end)"?

Comment: I don't really know what you're asking but the 27 club is not connected to money but to wildness and youth. Not everyone cited in the list you can find on wikipedia was rich. Some were not even famous at the time of their deaths.

Comment: end, 4.a: "[an outcome worked toward; purpose](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/end)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never heard this phrase, so I don't know it's normal context. As a stand-alone phrase, I'd personally *assume* that it means "opulence is the objective," per [Merriam-Webster's 4(a)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/end), "*an outcome worked toward; purpose*."

Imagine a conversation where it might be used:

> "Why did you get into the stock-trading business, Harry?"
>
> "Nothing less than the pursuit of opulence! When it comes to old Harry's life plan, stock-trading is the means, and opulence is the end."

*End* can also mean "*death; destruction*" (per M-W's 2(a) definition):

> Opulence was the end of Sally: after a lavish night of drunken partying, she crashed her million-dollar convertible into oncoming traffic.